# DotnetNuke RSS Feed Modules

Tags: rss, dotnetnuke-module

I am looking for information on how to get a DotNetNuke RSS Feed Module to work.

I have tried both DotNetNuke Modules 4.0.1 and 4.2.1 and I get errors. I have tried different settings in the module but nothing works.  When I take the link and post it in a browser (I've tried IE and Firefox) it works, so it shouldn't be a RSS problem.

I have tried several RSS feed URLs and get the same error. Thanks in advance for any help! I have looked at several websites regarding this issue but so far I have not found an answer.

**Error Message**

System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.Modules.XML.XmlController'. 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) 
at DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection.CreateType(String TypeName, String CacheKey, Boolean UseCache, Boolean IgnoreErrors)

Comment: Could you please paste the error somewhere?

Comment: This is what the message says in the event viewerMessage: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'DotNetNuke.Modules.XML.XmlController'. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) at DotNetNuke.Framework.Reflection.CreateType(String TypeName, String CacheKey, Boolean UseCache, Boolean IgnoreErrors)

Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error message it looks like there is something missing from the install of the module.  You will want to confirm that DotNetNuke.Modules.XML.dll exists within the /bin folder of your site.

Comment: No that DLL is not in the bin folder.  Can you tell me where can I get that?  Or do I need to re-install the RSS News feed module. Thxs

Comment: I re-installed DotNetNuke Module 4.0.1 and I still don't have the file DotNetNuke.Modules.XML.dll in the bin folder.  Can anyone tell me how to get this file. Thxs

Comment: I loaded the DotNetNuke.Modules.XML.dll and now I am getting a download error.